# Magnific Pop close button missing when modal is enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I'm using the [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html) jquery plugin to display a lightbox (gallery) inside a modal. My code is as follows:

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
        items:items,
        type:'image',
        modal:true, 
        closeOnContentClick:true, 
        closeOnBgClick:true, 
        showCloseBtn:true, 
        enableEscapeKey:true,
        gallery: {
          enabled: true,
          preload: [0,3], 
        },          
        removalDelay: 500,
        mainClass: 'mfp-fade',      
    });
```

I need to set the `modal` to `true` else, the lightbox gallery tend to close unexpectedly. It's a known issue happening in a lot of lightboxes.
The downside of this `modal` to `true` setting, is that the close buttons don't work.

Has anyone in a similar situation found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You are same as me.
I've solved this problem such like below code.

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
    items: {
        src: '#modifyDialog',
        type: 'inline',
        focus: '#engTxtareaModify',
    },

    modal: true,
    fixedContentPos: true,
    callbacks: {
        open: function () {
            var html = "<button title='Close (Esc)' type='button' class='mfp-close'></button>";
            $('.modifyDialog').append(html);
        }
    }
})
```

So, you can check that HTML codes. And then, I added a css code.

```
.mfp-close {  color: #333; }
```

I hope this to help you.